# Cannot add Excel to Project as a COM object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com

I am needing to create an Excel spreadsheet from a c# project, but I cannot add the reference to the Excel COM object.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and office 2013. I've clicked on the References folder and selected Add Reference, and then navigated to the COM tab, setting them in alphabetical order. I looked through, but there was no reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Trying to resolve the issue, I downloaded and installed the PIAs for Office 2010, but references still were not added. I'm not sure where these files would be located on the hard-drive, so I cannot just browse to them (or copy one to the project Resource folder and reference it there).

Does anyone have an idea as to why I cannot see the references?

**Additional Information**

I managed to get the Microsoft.Office.Interop.dll file from a coworker for Office 2013, but I was not able to reference it from my project since I am working in .NET 3.5. My manager does not want me to update the project to .NET 4.0, so it looks like I will need to use the Office 2010 PIAs I installed. Unfortunately, installing them did not add them to the list, and I haven't been able to find the dll's to add them by browsing to them.

I doubt that it will make a difference, but my dev system is Windows 8.

Comment: Try the "NET" tab ("Assemblies"), Excel interop should be there.

Comment: @Nikolay - I tried searching for Microsoft.Office... in the .Net tab, and there were no entries. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Check out [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It's a lot easier to work with than the Interops.

Comment: PIAs are obsolete, Microsoft doesn't ship them anymore for Office 2013.  You need another manager.  And use the "Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library" entry in the COM tab.

Comment: @HansPassant - Unfortunately, I have no references to Excel in the COM or .NET tabs that I have been able to find.

Comment: You must have Office installed on your dev machine of course.

Comment: @HansPassant - I have Office 2013 installed.

Comment: That's weird. Do you have them on your machine after all? Try searching the \Windows\assembly folder.

Comment: @Nikolay - I do have Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel under Windows\assembly.

Comment: Could you try to add a reference to that DLL in Windows\assembly (using "Browse.."). Maybe you'll get some error message explaining what's going on.